# How can I get values null after inner join?

Tags: mysql

I have this structure:

> **Table A --**   |id_A | field_1a | id_B | value_A|
>
> **Table B --**   |id_B | field_1b | field_2b | value_B|
>
> **Table C --**   |field_1c | id_D | id_A|
>
> **Table D --**   |id_D | description|

I want to get a query which returns:

-- Value A and if this value is null, returns its value in B.

-- Description of Table D through Table C. If row is not in C returns null.

I achieved the first part but I am stuck in the second part. As far as I tried this is my query:

```
select a.id_A
if (VALOR_b is null, VALOR_a, VALOR_b) as valor,
d.description 
from A a inner join B b 
on a.id_B = b.id_B
 inner join C c
on c.id_A = A.id_A
 inner join D d 
on d.id_D = c.D
```

As I said I am getting the first part and just the values what I can cross through C, but I need when I can cross them a null value in the previously part of the query.

Hoping I explain clear enough. Please, ask me any doubt.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `left join` to both `C` and `D`.
Also your life will be easier if you use the SQL standard `coalesce()` instead of `if ()`:

```
select
    a.id_A,
    coalesce(VALOR_a, VALOR_b) as valor,
    d.description 
from A a
join B b on a.id_B = b.id_B
left join C c on c.id_A = A.id_A
left join D d on d.id_D = c.D
```

`Left join` still returns a row from the parent table if there is no matching row, in which case it returns all nulls from the joined table"

`coalesce()` takes any number of arguments and returns the first non-null value.